# How to dynamically perform a weighted random row selection in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following table for an app where a student is assigned task to play educational game.

Student{id, last_played_datetime, total_play_duration, total_points_earned}

The app selects a student at random and assigns the task. The student earns a point for just playing the game. The app records the date and time when the game was played and for how much duration. I want to randomly select a student and assign the task. At a time only one student can be assigned the task. To give equal opportunity to all students I am dynamically calculating weight for the student using the date and time a student last played the game, the total play duration and the total points earned by the student. A student will then be randomly choosen influenced on the weight.

How do I, in PostgreSQL, randomly select a row from a table depending on the dynamically calculated weight of the row?

The weight for each student is calculated as follows: (minutes(current_datetime - last_played_datetime) * 0.75 + total_play_duration * 0.5 + total_points_earned * 0.25) / 1.5

Sample data:

```
+====+======================+=====================+=====================+
| Id | last_played_datetime | total_play_duration | total_points_earned |
+====+======================+=====================+=====================+
| 1  | 01/02/2011           | 300 mins            |  7                  |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2  | 06/02/2011           | 400 mins            |  6                  |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 3  | 01/03/2011           | 350 mins            |  8                  |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 4  | 22/03/2011           | 550 mins            |  9                  |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 5  | 01/03/2011           | 350 mins            |  8                  |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 6  | 10/01/2011           | 130 mins            |  2                  |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 7  | 03/01/2011           |  30 mins            |  1                  |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 8  | 07/10/2011           |   0 mins            |  0                  |
+----+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Sample data *in a text table format* would be a big help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that works as follows:

- first compute the weight of each student
- sum the weight of all students and multiply if by a random seed
- then pick the first student above that target, random, weight

Query:

```
with 
    student_with_weight as (
        select 
            id,
            (
                extract(epoch from (now() - last_played_datetime)) / 60 * 0.75
                + total_play_duration * 0.5
                + total_points_earned * 0.25
            ) / 1.5 weight
        from student
    ),
    random_weight as (
        select random() * (select sum(weight) weight from student_with_weight ) weight
    )
select id 
from 
    student_with_weight s
    inner join random_weight r on s.weight >= r.weight
order by id
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Why does this query work to produce the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cumulative sum on the weights and compare to `rand()`.  It looks like this:

```
with s as (
      select s.*, 
             <your expression> as weight
      from s
     )
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             sum(weight) over (order by weight) as running_weight,
             sum(weight) over () as total_weight
      from s
     ) s cross join
     (values (random())) r(rand)
where r.rand * total_weight >= running_weight - weight and
      r.rand * total_weight < running_weight;
```

The `values()` clause ensures that the random value is calculated only once for the query.  Funky things can happen if you put `random()` in the `where` clause, because it will be recalculated for each comparison.

Basically, you can think of the cumulative sum as dividing up the total count into discrete regions.  The `rand()` is then just choosing one of them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Gordon! Please could you explain why and how the query works?